# IE11 'Enable Protected Mode' is breaking the 'Application Cache'

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, offline-caching, offlineapps

**Background:**

I am building an html5 offline application that should get cached into the browser once it is loaded from the server.
I use 'Application Cache' and manifest file to get my page working in offline.

My application is running on a Java Oracle weblogic server.

**Issue:**

In IE11 I get 'Application cache fatal error' when the page is loaded from server and the page wouldn't work offline.

**Please have a look at an interesting thing that I noted after playing with the IE11 browser and my web page.**

1) In my IE11 browser the 'Enable Protected Mode' option is selected at two places

Internet Options> Security > Local Intranet

Internet Options> Security >Trusted sites

2) If I untick the above mentioned 'Enable Protected Mode' options from the internet option settings and then the page is loaded correctly. I can see that the  'Application Cache' and manifest are created correctly. No error is thrown at the console....thats good

3) If I turn of my weblogic server and try to access the page then the page is loaded correctly from the local Application cache....thats good

4) If I restart my laptop then the IE11 settings switch back to the 'Enable Protected Mode' and now if I try to access the page then IE11 won't load the page as the server is turned off... If I untick  the 'Enable Protected Mode' then the page gets displayed again from the cache.

**My questions:**

1) What is the 'Enable Protected Mode' doing with  my page's offline capability

2) How should I resolve this issue ?